# C usar write para imprimir un int

Tags: c, unix

tengo que hacer un programa que imprima del 0 al 9 usando el método write(). Mi problema es que no me imprime nada por pantalla. Este es el código:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void print() {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 10) {
        write(1, &i, 1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Supongo que es por el tamaño del int, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo. ¿Alguna idea?

PD: No puedo usar ninguna función predefinida a parte de write().

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `write()` lo que envía son bytes. Y si tu variable `i` es de tipo `int` y tiene el valor 0, lo que enviará `write()` será un byte de valor 0.

Por su parte la terminal espera códigos ascii. Si recibe un 0 lo interpretará como ascii nulo, que es invisible. Lo mismo pasará con los ascii 1, 2, ... que recibirá seguidamente. Todos ellos son ascii de control que no dan lugar a una salida visible (tal vez un tabulador).

Lo que necesitas enviarle a la pantalla es el código ascii del carácter '0', del carácter '1', etc.. en lugar de un byte de valor 0, 1, etc...

La forma más simple de conseguirlo es sumarle al valor que tenga `i` el código ascii del '0' que es 48. No necesitas saberte este valor de memoria y ni siquiera buscarlo en internet. Si usas el literal `'0'` el compilador lo sustituirá por el código ascii del cero.

Por tanto tu código habría que reescribirlo así:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

void print() {
    int i = 0;
    char ascii;

    while (i < 10) {
        ascii = i +'0';
        write(1, &ascii, 1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Observa por otro lado que eso hará salir "pegados" todos los dígitos. Si quisieras que salieran en líneas separadas sería necesario enviar a la terminal el ascii del retorno de carro (que es 10) y el de línea nueva (que es 13).

**Nota**. El tamaño del `int` no influye en este caso, porque al hacer la operación `i + '0'` y guardar el resultado en la variable `ascii` que es de tipo `char` solo cabe un byte. El resultado se truncará para que quepa en un byte (de todas formas ese resultado no va a ser nunca mayor a 255, por lo que siempre cabe). En tu código original tampoco era un problema (el problema era otro), porque sólo emitías 1 byte del número hacia la terminal, y en arquitecturas *little-endian* como las intel el byte volcado sería justamente el más bajo que es el que va tomando los valores 0, 1, 2,...

Comment: Lo entendí perfectamente, muchas gracias.